# Merge two files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, join

I have this file1.txt

```
deiauk 9
kespaul 8
luktol 7 
titkur 6
```

and other file2.txt

```
kespaul b
deiauk a
```

And I want to merge both files in one by first value, so my result should be

```
deiauk 9 a
kespaul 8 b
luktol 7 
titkur 6
```

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in file2.txt -- it should be "kespaul" not "kepsaul". Copy-and-paste at your own risk!

Comment: Why is there 4 spaces before `deiauk 9 a`? Is it the expected output?

Comment: No I edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sort file2.txt | join -a 1 file1.txt -
```

*join* requires sorted input. The '-' specifies that standard input will be used for the second file, which allows the output of *sort* to be used as input. The '-a 1' specifies that non-matching lines from the first file will be included in the output.

Comment: Actually, I think heemayl's solution, in the comment to another answer, is better than mine, since it's a more generalized solution. Mine only works if file1.txt is already sorted.
     join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt)

Answer (score 4):

You can use join command (will be good to have files sorted)

```
join file1.txt file2.txt -a 1
```

Comment: Although `sort`-ing is needed too..

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { k[$1]=$2; next }
  { print $0, k[$1] }
' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Note: This `awk` solution works also on unsorted raw input data; no need for additional expensive processes.

Answer (score 1):

Files must be sorted, so here's everything on one line.

```
sort file1.txt > f1s ; sort file2.txt >f2s ; join  -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 -a 2 f1s f2s ; rm f1s f2s
```

Comment: Use `join -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt)`

Comment: Nice improvement !